# Find adjoint$(2A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A=\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}2 & 52&152\\4 & 106&358\\6&162&620\end{array} } \right]$,then find adjoint$(2A)$.

---

I know the process of finding the adjoint of a matrix.The formula is transpose of the cofactor matrix.But in this question,numbers are quite big,so the calculation of cofactors will be very big.
Is there any short method by which calculations can be reduced?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For any matrix $A$ holds the identity $$A \cdot\operatorname{adjoint}(A) = (\det A) \cdot I$$
Your matrix $A$ is invertible so it follows that $$\operatorname{adjoint}(A) = (\det A)\cdot A^{-1}$$

For $2A$ we have $\det(2A) = 2^3\det A = 8\det A$ and $(2A)^{-1} = 2^{-1}A^{-1} = \frac12 A^{-1}$. Therefore
$$\operatorname{adjoint}(2A) = \det (2A)\cdot (2A)^{-1} = 4 (\det A)\cdot A^{-1} = 4\operatorname{adjoint}(A)$$

Comment: But still finding the adjoint A is very tedious

Comment: @user984325 You can find $\det A$ and $A^{-1}$ which is less tedious.

Comment: @user984325 Also write $A = 8\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 26 & 76 \\ 2 & 53 & 179 \\ 3 & 81 & 310\end{bmatrix}$ to reduce numbers.

Comment: Yes now I can do

Comment: Be careful, the formula is $A^{-1}=\frac{adj(A)}{det(A)} \Rightarrow adj(A)=det(A)\cdot A^{-1}$. Hence: $adj(2A)=4adj(A)$.

Comment: @farruhota You're right, thanks for the correction!